# How to deserialize nested django object

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm not really sure how I'm able to access the data of a nested serializer, with a one-to-many relation.

Here's my models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

class Title(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(
        Album,
        related_name='titles'
    )
```

then I have 2 serializers:

```
class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    titles = TitleSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'titles']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        album = Album.objects.create(
            id=validated_data.get('id'),
            name=validated_data.get('name')
        )

        titles = validated_data.pop('titles')
        for title in titles:
            title['album'] = album
            _title = Title(**title)
            _title.save()
        return album


class TitleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Title
        fields = ['name']
```

To deserialize and save I run the following:

```
album = AlbumSerializer(data=input_json)
album.is_valid()
album.save()
```

my problem is now, that I'm unable to access the items. Accessing the type of `album.instance.titles` gets me `<class 'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager.<locals>.RelatedManager'>`.
How can I get the titles out of it, or what am I doing wrong that I do not get a list of Titles in there?

Comment: I don't see `album.instance.titles` in your code, did I miss something?

Comment: the instance is basically one of the fields from the serializer, and contains the model object, in this case the album class, because the album itself is the album serializer object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `all()` on a `RelatedManager` to execute the DB query and get the results

```
album.instance.titles.all()
```

A `RelatedManager` is just like a normal model manager (`Model.objects`) that retrieves objects filtered by the relation